# str_replace with text files and array

Tags: arrays, fopen, str-replace, explode

I am having trouble understanding this. I've read many other posts here and elsewhere but I just don't get it. I think maybe because I have a hard time visualizing other's examples.  Could someone please give me some insight as to what I am doing wrong here.

```
1. $data = file_get_contents("rawtext.txt");
2.   
3. $kList[0] = "uszips.txt";
4. $kList[1] = "cities.txt";
5. $kList[2] = "states.txt";
6. 
7. foreach($kList as $replacelist)
8. {
9. 
10. 
11. $fp = @fopen($kList, 'r'); 
12. if ($fp) { 
13.  $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($kList))); 
14. } 
15. 
16.     $replacelist = str_replace($array,"", $data);   }
17. 
18. // remove stuff less than 2 characters, 
19. $data = preg_replace("!\\b\\w{1,2}\\b!", "", $data);  
20. // remove blank lines.
21. $data = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $data);
22. 
23. //save it back:
24. file_put_contents("stripped.txt",$data); 
25.
```

@DarkXphenomenon I get these notices

- Notice: Undefined variable: array in
  C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\str_replace.php on line 16
- Notice: Undefined
  variable: array in C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\str_replace.php on line 16
- Notice: Undefined variable: array in
  C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\str_replace.php on line 16

Thanks for that @ tip. I removed it and now I get this in addition.

- Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\str_replace.php on line
- Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tools\str_replace.php on line

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that can only mean that the file itself was not opened for reading. 
If it had entered the following, $array would have been set.

```
if ($fp) { 
 $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($kList))); 
}
```

So you should check if the file actually exists. At the time of testing, you should remove the error suppression `@` as it will make debugging faster.

**EDIT:** In your `for-each` loop you should use the $replacelist variable inside, not the entire array. It should be

```
foreach($kList as $replacelist)
{
$fp = @fopen($replacelist, 'r');
... 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the @ it and pasted the result above.